# Как сделать вечные кнопки @commands.Cog.listener()

Tags: python, discord

Помогите сделать вечные кнопки в nextcord.

````
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(1009917009175269417)
        info = self.bot.get_channel(1009917009175269417)
        rolestmoder = message.guild.get_role(942397028825169938)
        gs_no = message.guild.get_role(942397028854542399)
        zgs_no = message.guild.get_role(942397028854542398)
        sledak_no = message.guild.get_role(942404384392871968)
        gs_getto = message.guild.get_role(942397028854542396)
        zgs_getto = message.guild.get_role(942397028837785628)
        sledak = message.guild.get_role(942397028837785625)
        psgs = message.guild.get_role(942502889799172096)
        timestamp = datetime.now(pytz.timezone(r'Europe/Moscow'))
        whitelist = ['gg1', 'gg2']

        groven=['gg']
        grove = message.guild.get_role(id)
        groved = message.guild.get_role(id)

        if message.channel == channel and not message.author.bot and (len(list(filter (lambda x : x in message.content.lower(), whitelist))) > 0):
            if message.channel == channel and not message.author.bot and (len(list(filter (lambda x : x in message.content.lower(), groven))) > 0):
                button = Button(label = 'Одобрить', style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id='pokaz')
                async def pokaz(interaction):
                    if message.channel == channel and not message.author.bot and (rolestmoder in interaction.user.roles or gs_no in interaction.user.roles or zgs_no in interaction.user.roles or gs_getto in interaction.user.roles or zgs_getto in interaction.user.roles or sledak in interaction.user.roles or sledak_no in interaction.user.roles or psgs in interaction.user.roles):
                        newtimestamp = datetime.now(pytz.timezone(r'Europe/Moscow'))
                        embedVar = nextcord.Embed(title="✅ | Забив капта", description=message.author.mention, color=0x00ff00)
                        embedVar.add_field(name="Текст забива", value=f'```{message.content}```', inline=True)
                        embedVar.add_field(name="Одобрено", value= interaction.user.mention, inline=False)
                        embedVar.set_footer(text=f'DeLorean \u200b{timestamp}', icon_url="https://cdn.nextcordapp.com/avatars/706621027953672253/3fcb6700f5e6fccb8e9e46b720c26208.png")
                        await info.send(embed=embedVar)
                        await yvedom.edit(embed=embedVar, view=None)
                button.callback = pokaz

                button2 = Button(label = 'Отклонить', style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.red, custom_id='pokaz2')
                async def pokaz2(interaction):
                    if message.channel == channel and not message.author.bot and (rolestmoder in interaction.user.roles or gs_no in interaction.user.roles or zgs_no in interaction.user.roles or gs_getto in interaction.user.roles or zgs_getto in interaction.user.roles or sledak in interaction.user.roles or sledak_no in interaction.user.roles or psgs in interaction.user.roles):
                        newtimestamp = datetime.now(pytz.timezone(r'Europe/Moscow'))
                        embedVar = nextcord.Embed(title=" | Забив капта", description=message.author.mention, color=0xFF4500)
                        embedVar.add_field(name="Текст забива", value=f'```{message.content}```', inline=True)
                        embedVar.add_field(name="Отказан", value= interaction.user.mention, inline=False)
                        embedVar.set_footer(text=f'DeLorean \u200b{timestamp}', icon_url="https://cdn.nextcordapp.com/avatars/706621027953672253/3fcb6700f5e6fccb8e9e46b720c26208.png")
                        await yvedom.edit(embed=embedVar, view=None)
                button2.callback = pokaz2
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***На nextcord никогда не писал, но тщательно проверил документацию. Всё аналогично discord.py***

Создайте класс с кнопками и в качестве таймаута передайте `None`. [Подробнее](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#view).

```py
class Buttons(nextcord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)  # важно

    @nextcord.ui.button(label="...", emoji="...", style=discord.ButtonStyle.<...>)
    async def button(self, interaction, button):
        ...
```

Также добавьте экземпляр данного класса к объекту бота.

```py
bot.add_view(Buttons())
```

При отправке сообщения, к которому будут прикреплены кнопки, также передаётся экземпляр.

[Пример](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#nextcord.TextChannel.send):

```py
await my_favourite_channel.send(
    embed=nextcord.Embed(...),
    view=Buttons()
)
```

Comment: На сколько я знаю, time как раз необязательно передавать. Тогда кнопка будет работать всё время.

Comment: @qrts Там по умолчанию 180 секунд выставлено.